# Printing method from class type list in C++

Tags: c++, class

In main() i try to create a list from class movieTorrent, push object from the same type and use toString() method to print it. But it only prints the variables from child class. Where i am wrong?

So, i have this base class:

```
class Torrent
{
public:
    string title;
    int size;
    string uploader;
    int downloads;

    Torrent(){}

    Torrent(string title, int size, string uploader, int downloads)
    {
        this->title = title;
        this->size = size;
        this->uploader = uploader;
        this->downloads = downloads;
    }

    Torrent(const Torrent &t)
    {
        title = t.title;
        size = t.size;
        uploader = t.uploader;
        downloads = t.downloads;
    }

    virtual string toString()
    {
        string info = "|Title : " + title + "\n|Size : " + to_string(size) + "\n|Uploader : " + uploader + "\n|Downloads: " + to_string(downloads) + "\n\n";
        return info;
    }
};
```

And this is the chid :

```
class movieTorrent : public Torrent
{
public:
    string director;
    int duration;
    string language;

    movieTorrent(){}

    movieTorrent(string title, int size, string uploader, int downloads, string director, int duration, string language) : Torrent(title, size, uploader, downloads)
    {
        this->title = title;
        this->size = size;
        this->uploader = uploader;
        this->downloads = downloads;
        this->director = director;
        this->duration = duration;
        this->language = language;
    }

    movieTorrent(const movieTorrent &mT)
    {
        director = mT.director;
        duration = mT.duration;
        language = mT.language;
    }

    string toString()
    {
        string info = "|Title : " + title + "\n|Size : " + to_string(size) + "\n|Uploader : " + uploader + "\n|Downloads: " + to_string(downloads) + "\n" + "|Director : " + director + "\n|Duration : " + to_string(duration) + "\n|Language : " + language + "\n\n";
        return info;
    }
};
```

I was trying different ways to inheritance, but without result.

The list i created was `list<movieTorrent> movieTorrents;`

The main() :

```
int main()
{
    cout << " -- Torrent Tracker --" << endl;
    list<movieTorrent> movieTorrents;
    movieTorrent mT;

    mT.title = "Find me";
    mT.size = 12300;
    mT.uploader = "NaNa Banana";
    mT.downloads = 1204;
    mT.director = "F F";
    mT.duration = 120;
    mT.language = "English";

    movieTorrents.push_back(mT);

    mT.title = "Angry Birds";
    mT.size = 67832;
    mT.uploader = "Zamunda Admin";
    mT.downloads = 7204;
    mT.director = "Angry Studios";
    mT.duration = 90;
    mT.language = "English";

    movieTorrents.push_back(mT);

    for(list<movieTorrent>::iterator it = movieTorrents.begin() ; it != movieTorrents.end() ; ++it)
    {
        cout << it->toString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I literally have only the director, duration and language. Other things from base class are 0 or empty string.

Comment: Unforced error. There is no need for custom copy constructor here. Both objects only have self-managing members.

Comment: Yes, i know. But is this the problem here?

Comment: Now it's a good question! Thanks.

Comment: `it->Torrent::toString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR version:

Remove the copy constructors. They are not necessary for classes that have no members that require special resource handing ([See Rule of Three/Five/Zero.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

## Explanation

```
movieTorrent(const movieTorrent &mT)
{
    director = mT.director;
    duration = mT.duration;
    language = mT.language;
}
```

doesn't invoke the copy constructor for the `Torrent` base class, so `Torrent`'s default constructor is used. You could

```
movieTorrent(const movieTorrent &mT) : Torrent(mT)
{
    director = mT.director;
    duration = mT.duration;
    language = mT.language;
}
```

but The Rule of Zero says there is no need for these copy constructors at all.

Comment: This answer is helpful. Unofrtunately i hvae to use it. My teacher wants them.

Comment: So be it. Use the final code block to give the teacher what they want, pass the class, and then do it right once you've escaped their clutches.

Comment: Thanks! It may be confusing, but it works! :)

Comment: What is the point of confusion? [The weird `:` in `movieTorrent(const movieTorrent &mT) : Torrent(mT)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)? Please let me know so I can clean up the question. It's very likely that I've been doing and underappreciating some complexity.